# rsync from ntfs to exfat drive size balloons out of proportion despite --inplace flag

Tags: rsync, backup, nvme, exfat

I recently had an issue with my NVME windows drive, and need to back up all the data from it. I'm currently working from a liveUSB of zorin and trying to use rsync to copy the data from the ntfs formatted filesystem of the NVME drive to an external drive with exfat formatting. (The drive is being used to store files that are no longer present in the NTFS drive I also need to save the data from.)

```
zorin@zorin:/media/zorin/Fox$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  2.8M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdf1        15G  2.7G   12G  19% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      2.1G  2.1G     0 100% /rofs
/cow             16G  1.9G   14G  12% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            16G  700K   16G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           3.2G  132K  3.2G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdg1        11T  8.6T  2.4T  79% /media/zorin/MEDIA
/dev/nvme0n1p3  931G  906G   25G  98% /media/zorin/Fox
```

`/dev/nvme0n1p3  931G  906G   25G  98% /media/zorin/Fox`
Is what I'm trying to back up; 906gb worth of data.
`/dev/sdg1        11T  8.6T  2.4T  79% /media/zorin/MEDIA`
Is the exfat formatted drive that I want to save the data to; with 2.4 TB free. However, every time I run rsync, it completely fills the external drive, and then errors out, saying `No space left on device (28)`, despite using the `--inplace` flag.
I've created the folder `backup_fox_12-11-23` and cd'd into it. I've tried:

```
zorin@zorin:/media/zorin/MEDIA/backup_fox_12-11-23$ rsync -r --progress /media/zorin/Fox .
```

```
zorin@zorin:/media/zorin/MEDIA/backup_fox_12-11-23$ rsync -r --progress --inplace /media/zorin/Fox .
```

```
zorin@zorin:/media/zorin/MEDIA/backup_fox_12-11-23$ time sudo rsync -hvrltD --modify-window=1 --stats --info=progress2 --inplace --dry-run /media/zorin/Fox .
```

Which ran through and ended with (as expected):

```
Number of files: 2,023,970 (reg: 1,650,008, dir: 373,772, link: 109, special: 81)
Number of created files: 2,023,970 (reg: 1,650,008, dir: 373,772, link: 109, special: 81)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 1,650,008
Total file size: 984.99G bytes
Total transferred file size: 984.99G bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 15.33M
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 69.96M
Total bytes received: 6.46M

sent 69.96M bytes  received 6.46M bytes  207.95K bytes/sec
total size is 984.99G  speedup is 12,888.96 (DRY RUN)

real    6m6.817s
user    0m17.857s
sys 1m53.906s
```

The 984.99G is more than the 906GB expected, but still well less than the 2.4T free on the external drive. However, when I run it without the `--dry-run`

```
zorin@zorin:/media/zorin/MEDIA/backup_fox_12-11-23$ time sudo rsync -hvrltD --modify-window=1 --stats --info=progress2 --inplace /media/zorin/Fox .
```

I see the storage space being used on the external ballooning way beyond what is being reported as transferred. I'm not sure what else to do, and could use any advice/suggestions.